# How to handle SSH-session using pexpect?

Tags: python, pexpect

I am trying to automate a small task that requires several steps and some of the steps would be identical for all the "devices":
- ssh login
- run a command
- clean after itself

I have a script that uses pexpect but for every function (task) I have to establish SSH connection which is lame.

What I am trying to do is kind of like this:

A function that would create a session and another functions that would use the same "child"

```
def ssh_login(device):
    child.spawn("ssh root@"+device)
    child.expect("password:")
    child.sendline(password)
    child.expect("#")
```

Another function that would use the session and run some command like

```
def run_command():
    # run some command here
    child.sendline("some_command")
    child.expect("#")
```

And a clean up function

```
def cleanup():
    child.sendline(cleanup)
    child.expect("#")
    child.sendline("exit")
    child.interract()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use an ssh-agent (and, preferably, public key auth) and just send the script as a command-line argument? You can do `ssh root@host '...multiple commands go here...'` without any issues.

Comment: Also, assuming this is the standard OpenSSH `ssh` command, you can use `ControlMaster` mode to launch a single SSH session that you then send various commands over. See `ControlMaster` in `ssh_config(5)`.

Comment: Show your existing code which you think is lame.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
pexpect.spawn('ssh', [ '-o' + 'ControlMaster=auto',username + "@" + hostname, '-o' + 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p'])
```

And you will find session:

```
ls ~/.ssh/master-yourname@hostname:22
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar. All you have to do is `return` the child from the `ssh_login` function and pass it along as an input to your other functions.

```py
def ssh_login(device):
    child = pexpect.spawn("ssh root@"+device)
    #Do your usual login
    return child
```

When you call it, save the child in a variable.

```py
session = ssh_login(my_device)
run_command(session)
cleanup(session)
```

Of course you will need to change the other functions to accept a session input:

```py
def run_command(session):
    # run some command here
    session.sendline("some_command")
    session.expect("#")

def cleanup(session):
    session.sendline(cleanup)
    session.expect("#")
    session.sendline("exit")
    session.interract()
```

Answer (score -1):

When I do anything with python and SSH, I use Paramiko, its a really solid module, Here's my "Starter Code" for any project that uses it. I've argmentized it, and added some comments, you'll probably want to generate a list of the servers you want to run the command on, and loop through it. I would reccomend though, if you need to frequently run commands on a lot of servers, consider getting something like Saltstack, or Ansible, they make it very easy to manage servers regularly.

https://saltstack.com/

https://www.ansible.com/

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

    import paramiko


    def run_ssh_cmd(remote_server, connect_user, identity, cmd=None):
        """ create an ssh connection to the remote server and retrieve
        information"""

        # kludge to make ssh work - add 'your_domain.com' to the remote_server
        remote_server += '.your_domain.com'

        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        client.connect(remote_server, username=connect_user, key_filename=identity)
        command_str = cmd
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command_str)

        print stdout.readlines()
        client.close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        import argparse
        import datetime

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

        parser.add_argument("-s", "--server", action="store", required=True,
                            dest="server", help="Server to query")
        parser.add_argument("-u", "--user", action="store", required=True,
                            dest="user", help="User ID for remote server connection")
        parser.add_argument("-i", "--identity", action="store", required=True,
                            dest="id_file", help="SSH key file")
        args = parser.parse_args()

        run_ssh_cmd(args.server, args.user, args.id_file, "hostname;date")
```